# PrimeNg TurboTable divide table into single components

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-turbotable

Does anyone have an idea how to use custom angular component inside turbo table? I mean my body, header sections are starting to grow and it’s getting really hard to read. When I try replacing what’s inside ng-template header or body I loose all the styling. It’s displaing only columns names but no css is applied. Can someone help me with that?

Comment: [Component styles normally apply only to the HTML in the component's own template](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep)

Comment: So I need to copy/paste all css for table with :host /deep/ selector? It doesn't look like the best solution... I'm using :host /deep/ in some cases where I need to override one or two styles but whole table? Also documentation states that it's deprecated